# Are there any Visual Studio plugins to maintain file bookmarks?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, project-management

I think that in a big project with many files, it is tedious to open the file by browsing directories (e.g. Windows Explorer) and open the file in Visual Studio [i know power command has a tool for search]

Is there a plug-in that supports file bookmarking in Visual Studio?  I'd like to bookmark the file I'm currently working on -- then if I need to access that file again, I can get to it quickly.

Comment: You can add files to relevant projects, selecting None as the build action.  This way, you'll be able to quickly access them through solution explorer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 has something that does almost everything you need

```
View -> Other Windows -> Bookmark Window
```

You can create virtual folders to organize your bookmarks. Click on anywhere in a code file, then click on "Toggle a bookmark on the current line", or `CTRL-B,T` if you have default mappings.

You can then just mark the top of the file for each file. The bookmark manager will let you open all your files easily.

**Update**

A gentleman is working on updating his "Favorites Add-in" for Visual Studio 2010 -> [Favorites Menu](http://www.utkarshonline.com/page/Favorites-Menu-for-Visual-Studio.aspx)

Comment: bookmark windows not help to open the all file. they just a feature to know them in future. i like the thing you want but i need to listed the file in the seprate windows as i see in Sollution navigator[by plugin]

Comment: @Ankit This will let you keep a list of all the files you want. I am not sure what you mean about knowing them in the future. The Bookmark Window show's all the files you bookmarked in a separate window. The only feature missing is a Select All Open All. Worst case, without a addin, you just keep hitting next through all of your bookmarks to open the files.

Comment: Seems that doing a pull from TFS voids the bookmarks. Makes some sense (line numbers change, etc, natch), but greatly diminishes the feature's usefulness if I'm not missing something.

Answer (score 3):

[Favorite Documents Visual Studio Add-in](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d4ab8421-147f-4416-8038-d5f7fdcf6a56) is similar to Favorites Menu, but works in Visual Studio 2010 and has more features. Check it out.

Comment: It would have been nice if it were possible to save links to specific functions or lines in the file (it doesn't seem so). Good suggestion nontheless.

Comment: v2.1 of Favorite Documents supports links to functions and specific lines.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the pinned window feature in VS2010.  Productivity Power Tools to the rescue!

Comment: i know it's a feature PPT gives but if i freshly open visual studio and want them their is not possible by that.

Comment: In my mind, a great bookmarking plug-in for VS2010 would work like Yahoo Delicious: it would allow you to save and restore bookmarks in the cloud, or on a company's Exchange server.

Comment: I agree with GregC, although you might need to save your project sources too on the cloud in that case (some companies might not like the idea). Also it would be nice to be able to create sub-folders to organize bookmarks.